# Suppress SMTP Response Email

Tags: ruby, email, smtp

I have an odd problem that I'm trying to solve with ruby's net/smtp library. Actually, I guess it's a general question about smtp. Basically, if the response is an error I don't want there to be an email telling me of a delivery failure (At least I don't want to see it). I want to accomplish this without using a filter in the GUI. I'm looking for a coding solution. I'm not sure if that's possible with the smtp protocol, but I figured I'd try. Here's my code so far:

```
msg = "Subject: Hi There!\n\nThis works, and this part is in the body."
smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'smtp.gmail.com', 587
smtp.enable_starttls
smtp.start("gmail.com", username, password, :login) do
  response = smtp.send_message(msg, email, recipients)
  p response.message
end
```

I've been reading around trying to figure out if this is even possible and I haven't found anything that says that it is possible.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "you don't want to see it"?

Comment: I've edited the question, but basically I'm looking for a code solution to either delete, archive or some other way to suppress the email error response.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that with SMTP especially when using gmail servers since they enforce proper from-fields so you cannot spoof your own mail address either. Handling and sending bounce messages is an inherent feature of SMTP, and you can't really change that from your end  in any reliable way.

Two alternative solutions come to mind:

a) Add a filter to your GMail account to handle bounce messages in whatever way you choose (delete them, put them in a separate folder, forward them etc.).

b) You can use a ruby GMail gem like https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail and programmatically scan your GMail account for bounces and then handle them in any way you choose just with plain ruby code.

Solution a) is very simple and requires very little setup, but it's not as flexible as what you can do with b). It depends on what you want to do and how you want to filter and handle bounces.